# DirectX: can't render a model from CMO

Tags: directx, directx-11, directxtk

I'm trying to draw a model using DirectX (following this tutorial: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Rendering-a-model?fbclid=IwAR3A0mw9rzjJHrN3mwgSb9a6oKqNgiDiAnnfkVLIIQVca9Og6cvfvscuVfE).

I've add my model.cmo file with **Add existing item** and following line to **Game::CreateDevice()**

```
m_model = Model::CreateFromCMO(m_d3dDevice.Get(), L"model.cmo", *m_fxFactory);
```

I can't build and run my project because of exception on aboved line

> Unhandled exception at 0x747318A2 in directX_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location 0x00B3F738. occurred

I will appreciate any tips on how to resolve or debug that issue

Answer (score 0):

You should enable "break on C++ exception" for the debugger as indicated in the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) for `std::exception` so you can see exactly what code triggered the exception.

> Note that more recent versions of the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/releases) provide more debug output for those kinds of failures which are probably 'file not found' or similar issue.

The *DirectX Tool Kit* also implements the [what](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/what/) method for it's C++ exceptions, so you can use this code to get more detail:

```
try
{
    m_model = Model::CreateFromCMO(m_d3dDevice.Get(), L"model.cmo", *m_fxFactory);
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.what();
    // Do some error handling here or call throw to re-throw it
}
```